# Which version of friendsofcake/bootstrap-ui matches with github

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I am starting out with Cakephp3 3.8.x, and am wanting to use BootStrap 4. Now, in Github, friendsofcake/Bootstrap-UI, there is master (BS3), develop (BS4) and cake-4-bs-4 branch. I am not wanting to install using git, but rather with composer. However, when you go into packagist, the closest is dev-develop and dev-cake-4-bs-4. I gather these are the equivalent. However, when do you use 2.0.0.-betax, or 3.0.0-betax and what do they relate to?

Answer (score 0):

You can see from the 'requires' panel on packagist.com.

So the branch `3.0.0-beta` is for CakePHP 4, whereas `2.0.0-beta6` is for CakePHP 3.

E.g. for the latter the 'requires' panel says:

- `cakephp/cakephp: ^3.7.0`

And no, the `develop` branch (`dev-master` on packagist) and `cake-4-bs-4` (`dev-cake-4-bs-4` on packagist) are not the same. If click on the expand button on packagist.com you will see this other branch at the bottom.

It seems that `dev-master` is CakePHP 3 and BS 4, whereas `dev-cake-4-bs-4` is for CakePHP 4 and BS4.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I went back and read my question.  If on Git there is cake-4-bs-4 and develop, why in Packagist is there the 2.0.0-betax and 3.0.0beta.  I would have thought that they would have followed the respective branches.

Comment: `2.0.0-beta6` etc. are tags, not branches. Tags also show up as versions, identical to branches.